# Deep Copy a template class

Tags: java, templates

Please hear me out!
Can someone please explain to me how templates/generics assignments work in memory?

I have a a base class with one T variable, and a copy constructor.
When I invoke the copy constructor, I get a deep copy of the built in (known) data types but the T points to the same address? What's causing this and how do I fix this?

In my Base Class:

```
protected T data;                      // stored data
protected int balanceFactor;           // balance factor (follow the definition in the textbook and slides exactly)
protected ThreadedAVLNode<T> left;     // right child
protected ThreadedAVLNode<T> right;    // left child
protected boolean hasThread;

public ThreadedAVLNode(ThreadedAVLNode<T> n) {


    this.data= n.data;
    this.balanceFactor=n.balanceFactor;
    this.hasThread=n.hasThread;
    this.height= n.height;


}
```

And inside my Main:

```
int var=0;
   ThreadedAVLNode myNode = new ThreadedAVLNode(var);
   myNode.height=1;
   myNode.balanceFactor=2;
    ThreadedAVLNode myNewNode = new ThreadedAVLNode(myNode);
```

[image: As you can see the template variables share the same address]

Comment: `Integer` is immutable, so it's fine to share it's instances.

Comment: Aha, I read that somewhere, thanks! how would I clone it then?

Comment: Oh i see, now. Concerning the way i did it will there ever be an instance where if i change one nodes T value then the other would change too?

Comment: Currently they share the same instance, so you either have to find a way to create a deep copy for them (I don't know of a generic way to do that) or only use immutable types.